# Error, Building the location based game scene in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapbox

I want to build the Mapbox scenes but I get this error

[image]

Comment: Please share the code + Share texts as texts.

Comment: @vahdet to be fair in this case it is probably not possible to copy and paste the error text

Answer (score 0):

The Library requirement is to use the Android API version 24 or greater.
Go to `Player Settings` and set the `Minimum API Level` to 24.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the error your selected minimum API (Android) version is `16` but you are using a library that requires at least `24`.

Go to the [Player Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsAndroid.html) (<kbd>Edit</kbd> → <kbd>Project Settings</kbd> → <kbd>Player</kbd>) to the Android tab and under [Identification](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsAndroid.html#Identification) increase the `Minimum API Level` to at least `24`